# How to retrieve JSON value in Android?

Tags: android, json, android-json

How can i retrieve this JSON value in int

```
{
"success": 1,
"message": "Product successfully retrieved."
}
```

I used this code but it doesn't work

```
JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject("success");
int a = obj.getInt("success");
Log.e("YASH", String.valueOf(a));

JSONObject msg = response.getJSONObject("message");
String m = msg.getString("message");
Log.e("YASH", m);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you have the JSONObject response, you don't need the response.getJSONObject.  You just need response.getInt("success") and response.getString("message")